# how to block unhelpful and hostile users from commenting and downvoting?

Tags: feature-request, abuse

There is a genuine requirement to block certain users who are not just unhelpful but hostile and who downvote your questions which makes them less attractive or visible to other users.

I know the common response of those who run this site is to ignore such users, but that doesn't prevent them downvoting.

Also the emotional labour should not be on the victims to deal with the behaviour of bad users.

The easiest solution is to have a block capability.

Comment: 'There is a genuine requirement to block certain users who are not just unhelpful but hostile' I don't believe you.  Convince me that you are not making up fake news by providing evidence, else it didn't happen.

Comment: Use rude/abusive or unkind flags for hostile comments, and if you suspect the downvotes are from the same person each time **and your posts are otherwise good and getting upvoted**, a mod flag asking for investigation is your solution. The 'block capability' is there already, it's called a suspension, and if your flags are correct one will follow. If not, it's a great thing you can't block since that means these users were correct and you shouldn't be able to block correct actions no matter how much you personally disagree with them.

Comment: Also, please go read [this interview](https://www.theatlantic.com/family/archive/2018/11/arlie-hochschild-housework-isnt-emotional-labor/576637/) and [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotional_labor) on emotional labor, as you don't seem to have understood what that actually is and how it totally doesn't apply here.

Comment: See [Why shouldn't I assume I know who downvoted my post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388686/4642212).

Answer (score 15):

I think the most likely reasons for a question to be downvoted is when another user (with the downvote privilege) thinks that the question:

> does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

That voting is anonymous, although someone may claim to have downvoted in an attached comment, so any attempts to block the downvoter might be somewhat hit or miss.

I think it is always best to focus on improving the content rather than trying to identify any downvoters.